# Keep Session open - Capybara/Cucumber

Tags: ruby, session, cucumber, capybara

I have a feature that requires in excess of 100 Scenarios to be run, the first step being to log into my application. this is normally handled with a `Before`  hook and a `After` hook which will log you out. This keeps my tests independent of each other and for me is normally a good idea. However in this instance I just want to log into my application, run all my scenarios and log out.

I seem to be having an issue with sessions as after a scenario has finished I am redirected to `about:blank` and my session is killed.

I have already tried

```
class Capybara::Selenium::Driver < Capybara::Driver::Base
def reset!
# Use instance variable directly so we avoid starting the browser just to reset the session
if @browser
  begin
    #@browser.manage.delete_all_cookies <= cookie deletion is commented out!
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError => e
    # delete_all_cookies fails when we've previously gone
    # to about:blank, so we rescue this error and do nothing
    # instead.
  end
  @browser.navigate.to('about:blank')
end
end
end
```

But then i get the error below in my console

```
expected not to find xpath "/html/body/*", found ...
```

So my question is how can i finish a scenario and then just click another link in my site and then conduct the next scenario

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of when it would be a good idea to use the [Background](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background) feature of Cucumber.

If you get the user to log in inside the background tag, they will be logged in for all subsequent scenarios.

Comment: thanks, unless I am misinterpreting though `The background is run before each of your scenarios but after any of your Before Hooks.` so it would still be run multiple times ?

Comment: Ah yeah, I misread!
You could potentially have a step that runs another batch of steps
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions

So, after logging in, have steps that fire off each of the steps of the different scenarios. Though there must be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

It turns out after reading the [Poltergeist Docs](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#manipulating-cookies) I could implement a simple solution

This is what I came up with:

```
Given(/^I setup the form with the correct template \- benchmarking$/) do
  if !defined? $i == true
    login_to_app
  elsif page.current_url == "about:blank"
    options = { domain: 'mydomain',
                httponly: true, 
                name: 'name',
                path: '/',
                secure: true
              }
   page.driver.set_cookie("name", $session_cookie, options)
   page.visit('url')
  end
   click_link('mylink')
   wait_for_ajax
end

Then('This is my final step')
  $i = 1
  $session_cookie = page.driver.cookies["PHPSESSID"].value
end
```

So in the first iteration `$i` is not defined so I can login, by the second scenario it is defined so this means I can then set the cookie info based on the last session and access the page I require in my application using the same credentials as if I had logged in.